# Is it possible to navigate to section in view from controller?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

The Controller should return to section Z of View Index , and not the top of the page

Controller :

```
ActionResult Action()
{

return View("Index#Y");   // How to return to section Z of Index
}
```

The view Index has 3 sections

View :

```
</section>

<section id="Y" >

</section>

<section id="Z" >
 @Html.Action("Submit","Action","Controller")
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply redirect to the appropriate section:

```
   public ActionResult Action()
   {
       return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index") + "#Y");
   }
```

Comment: Using `return Redirect(Url.Action("Index") + "#Y");` worked just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial view for each section and return partial view from controller as shown below:

```
    return PartialView("_SectionZ", youViewModelOptional);
```

To know more about partial view refer this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249475/set-page-scroll-position-on-page-load-of-mvc-app) is a similar question that will help solve your problem.
Basically what you need to use is,

```
window.location = '#Y';
```

You can get more detail about this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index", new { "#Y" });
}
```