# Set page scroll position on page load of MVC view with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to automatically go to the bottom of the web page upon page load. On the get AND the post, in fact, no matter how the view has been called, it has to go automatically to the bottom of the page.

I want to do it with javascript.

Seemed like something simple, something I could find in here easily. Well this looks like it :

[Set page scroll position on page load of MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249475/set-page-scroll-position-on-page-load-of-mvc-app/2249506#2249506)

There is only one problem... The answer doesn't put the javascript solution in context. And without context... I have no idea where to put these line, no matter what I try...

I won't play all day to know how to accomplish this, so HERE'S A CONTEXT :

```
@model WhateverModelYouWant
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Formulaire de reprise";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("ImportantStuff").scrollIntoView();
</script>

<h2> TITLE OF THE VIEW <h2>

<div> Lots of content here </div>

<div> Even more content here </div>

<div id="ImportantStuff"> Important stuff here </div>

<input type="submit" value="ImportantButton" >
```

Needless to say this doesn't make the page scroll anywhere... Thanks in advance.

**ERROR :**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example nothing can be scrolled anyway because everything is in the visible area. Apart from that mituw16 already gave you the right solution. Here is an example how to use the scrollIntoView function.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        function scrollToImportantStuff() {
            document.getElementById('ImportantStuff').scrollIntoView()
        }
        window.onload = scrollToImportantStuff;
</script>
    
    <h2> TITLE OF THE VIEW <h2>

    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ImportantStuff').scrollIntoView()" value="Scroll ImportantStuff into View" />

    <div style="height:500px;"> Lots of content here </div>

    <div style="height:500px;"> Even more content here </div>

    <div id="ImportantStuff"> Important stuff here </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to with MVC. It is accomplished with javascript.

```
document.getElementById("ImportantStuff").scrollIntoView();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Comment: Thanks... But this is another answer without context. See my edit, I think this is what you wanted me to do. And it doesn't scroll neither...

Comment: It's without context because what you're asking to do is extremely simple. I didn't think it need more "context"....

Comment: Sorry that you take it this way... The goal was not to frustrate anyone. This might have seemed too simple for you...